# Changing default settings for Arrow Item in print layout of QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I am using the print layout of QGIS 3.10 to make maps and some reports. I frequently use the Arrow Layout Item.

I need to change the default values for the Arrow Stroke Color, Arrow Stroke Width, Arrow Stroke Color and Arrow Fill Color. In my layout otherwise, I have to do this every time for all the arrow items across multiple projects.Since Arrows are very specific, copying and pasting it again also is not very helpful.

Is there a way to change these default values like we can change the default value of the font?